# How I select record that not appear in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table: Movie

```
mID title                   year    director
101 Gone with the Wind  1939    Victor Fleming
102 Star Wars           1977    George Lucas
103 The Sound of Music  1965    Robert Wise
104 E.T.                    1982    Steven Spielberg
105 Titanic                 1997    James Cameron
106 Snow White          1937    <null>
107 Avatar                  2009    James Cameron
108 Raiders of the Lost Ark 1981    Steven Spielberg
```

Table: Rating

```
rID mID stars   ratingDate
201 101 2   2011-01-22
201 101 4   2011-01-27
202 106 4   <null>
203 103 2   2011-01-20
203 108 4   2011-01-12
203 108 2   2011-01-30
204 101 3   2011-01-09
205 103 3   2011-01-27
205 104 2   2011-01-22
205 108 4   <null>
206 107 3   2011-01-15
206 106 5   2011-01-19
207 107 5   2011-01-20
208 104 3   2011-01-02
```

I need to fetch movies which are not rate yet. In this case Titanic (mID 105) and Star Wars (mID 102) never get rate in rating table.

I figured out it with

> select distinct movie.title from movie,rating where
>   rating.mid!=movie.mid except select distinct movie.title from
>   movie,rating where rating.mid=movie.mid

however I think it might have better (easier/cleaner) way to do.

Comment: Hint: `... LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ratingDate IS NULL`

Comment: @HLGEM Disagree - implicit joins are not an antipattern, they are merely not part of the SQL ANSI standard which explicitly defines the JOIN syntax. Given that implicit joins have existed since Codd, predate the ANSI standard by a considerable margin, and have absolutely no difference in performance paths than explicit joins, this is a stylistic preference only.

Comment: No it is not a stylistic prefernce. Implict joins cause problems,. You can create accidental corss joins, if you use a comniation of innner and outer joins, you can get bad results, And tey are harder to maintain. THey are a documented antipattern. There is no advantage to using them and many minuses. Perhaps you should read:http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Programmers-ebook/dp/B00A376BB2/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1377180059&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
SELECT Movies.* FROM Movies LEFT JOIN Rating ON Movies.mID = Rating.mID WHERE Rating.mID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question properly, that looks like textbook application of [outer joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join).

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE mid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(mid) FROM Rating)

Basically it will select all records from the movie table that are not in the rating table, linking them on the 'mid' column, which I am assuming is a unique identifier.

Answer (score 3):

I will add another possibility.

```
Select [list columns here]
from Movie m
where NOT exists (SELECT * FROM RATING r where m.mid = r.mid)
```